# If $h=g^{(p-1)/4}$ show $h^2=-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $g$ be a generator of the multiplicative group {$1, 2, \cdots, p-1$} and set $h=g^{(p-1)/4}$ where $p$ is a prime with $p\equiv 1\pmod 4)$.

I would appreciate help showing $h^2=-1\pmod p$.

I know from quadratic reciprocity that the Legendre symbol $(-1/p)=1$ so $-1$ is a square modulo $p$. And I have tried several examples which, of course, work.

But I would like to be able to show it directly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $w=h^2=g^{(p-1)/2}$. Then by Fermat's Theorem, $w^2\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, so $w\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ or $w\equiv -1\pmod{p}$. But $w\not\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, since $g$ is a generator.